# How can I translate Chinese and Japanese text without typing it?

Tags: languages

When I'm in Japan or China, there are barely any European alphabet and I want to use my camera to take a photo of a sign and convert it into English language. Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Really? Everywhere I went in Japan last year the signs were bilingual.

Comment: It depends om what place in Japan Most famous place has both language but all places. Strongly believe that it will be a standard in the future.'

Comment: Do you know any app for it?

Comment: As far as I remember, [Google Goggles](http://www.appbrain.com/app/google-goggles/com.google.android.apps.unveil) lists this among its features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate) app, you can take photos which contain texts using the app and it'll detect it and translate it.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Although the Google Translate app should take care of you in some cases, it doesn't always function properly in China. Straight text conversion (not images) tends to work in most cases for me, but when I use the updated app and attempt to use local images or ones that I take at the time of translation (two options) it tends to give out a server error. Of course, there's also the option to "write" it in yourself now so maybe you would be willing to give that a shot too.